# How to regroup text via css?

Tags: html, css

I need to regroup my text when I reduce the page size. The current behavior is like this: when I change my page size the text is not regrouping. How can I fix it?

Here is my Fiddle `example`:

```
https://jsfiddle.net/v7386L2a
```

PS:

I can't use `width: XX%;` because I want to remove spaces when I reduce page size.

Comment: What do you mean by regrouping?

Comment: I want to see the whole text when I change the page size.

Comment: Oh, you mean you don't need to overflow in the x direction.

Comment: Yes, I don't need overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove the width property `(if you do need a width use max-width instead of width)` and use word-wrap like this. Apply the css on the div instead of main. And now you can try to resize the page and see if that's what you needed.

```css
div {
    max-width:1024px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: rgba(117, 128, 128, 0.27);
    word-wrap:break-word;
}
```

```html
<main>
    <div>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque quis lectus ut dui iaculis vehicula.
        Vestibulum molestie nunc id odio condimentum, eu efficitur justo laoreet. Phasellus urna elit, fringilla ut
        tempus
        sed, varius non augue. Proin tempor, odio nec malesuada bibendum, tortor lorem elementum risus, facilisis
        fringilla
        nunc mauris ac nisi. Nulla porta ac arcu quis eleifend. Nunc vulputate leo non lorem interdum commodo. Aliquam
        ac
        massa maximus, pharetra velit ac, lobortis lorem. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes,
        nascetur ridiculus mus. Mauris vehicula interdum semper. Pellentesque tincidunt eget dui eu placerat. Curabitur
        auctor dui ac est scelerisque, in fringilla nibh mollis. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing
        elit.
        Pellentesque quis lectus ut dui iaculis vehicula. Vestibulum molestie nunc id odio condimentum, eu efficitur
        justo
        laoreet. Phasellus urna elit, fringilla ut tempus sed, varius non augue. Proin tempor, odio nec malesuada
        bibendum,
        tortor lorem elementum risus, facilisis fringilla nunc mauris ac nisi. Nulla porta ac arcu quis eleifend. Nunc
        vulputate leo non lorem interdum commodo. Aliquam ac massa maximus, pharetra velit ac, lobortis lorem. Orci
        varius
        natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Mauris vehicula interdum semper.
        Pellentesque tincidunt eget dui eu placerat. Curabitur auctor dui ac est scelerisque, in fringilla nibh mollis.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque quis lectus ut dui iaculis vehicula.
        Vestibulum molestie nunc id odio condimentum, eu efficitur justo laoreet. Phasellus urna elit, fringilla ut
        tempus
        sed, varius non augue. Proin tempor, odio nec malesuada bibendum, tortor lorem elementum risus, facilisis
        fringilla
        nunc mauris ac nisi. Nulla porta ac arcu quis eleifend. Nunc vulputate leo non lorem interdum commodo. Aliquam
        ac
        massa maximus, pharetra velit ac, lobortis lorem. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes,
        nascetur ridiculus mus. Mauris vehicula interdum semper. Pellentesque tincidunt eget dui eu placerat. Curabitur
        auctor dui ac est scelerisque, in fringilla nibh mollis.
    </div>
</main>
```